# ¿Cómo mostrar en una matriz el valor total como valor numérico y como porcentaje el resto de columnas?

Tags: powerbi

Soy relativamente nueva en PowerBi y tengo la duda de si se podría implementar en una misma matriz valores como porcentaje y el total que muestre la suma de esos valores

En la siguiente imagen muestro mi tabla con la suma de valores para cada una de las columnas. Me gustaría mostrar los valores de cada una de las columnas como porcentaje del total de una línea y en el total de línea de la matriz, que me siga apareciendo el total en valor numérico tal y como se muestra en la imagen, para que al mostrarme el total de las columnas anteriores, sepa sobre el total que estoy trabajando.

[image: Esta la imagen de mi tabla]

Ya que si muestro los valores como porcentaje del total de una línea, el total de la línea siempre aparecerá el 100% y no sabré el total sobre el que me está mostrando ese porcentaje tal y como os muestro en la siguiente imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la siguiente imagen les muestro como quiero que me muestre la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es poner la medida dos veces en `Valores`:

[image: Dos campos en el rol de Valores en Power BI]

La primera medida la cambias a *Mostrar valor como* > *Porcentaje del total de fila*, y la segunda medida la dejas como *Ningún cálculo*:

[image: Cambiar Mostrar valor como en uno de los dos campos en Power BI]

Esto crea una matriz como la siguiente:

[image: Matriz en Power BI]

Entonces, puedes ocultar las columnas que no necesitas, por ejemplo:

[image: Ocultando columnas de matriz en Power BI]

Asegúrate de desactivar *Ajuste automático de línea* para que el texto no se expanda verticalmente:

[image: Ajuste automático de línea en Power BI]

Comment: Como oculto las líneas que no necesito?

Comment: Con el mouse, arrastrando el borde de la columna. Acabo de actualizar mi respuesta con un GIF.